# How to connect MSSQL database to PowerShell or vise versa

Tags: powershell

I am new to powershell and I have been tasked to use powershell scripting to leverage the ability to connect to MSSQL database.

I have powershell 5.1 and this is the information of my MSSQL:

Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio                      14.0.17099.0

Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools                        14.0.513.48

Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)                     6.1.7601.17514

Microsoft MSXML                     3.0 6.0

Microsoft Internet Explorer                     9.11.9600.18665
Microsoft .NET Framework                        4.0.30319.42000

Operating System                        6.1.7601

Like I said, I am totally new to power shell and haven't had many practices yet. Thank you.

Comment: [This StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25682703/connect-to-sql-server-database-from-powershell) may be relevant. Also some of the results of [This Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=powershell+connect+to+mssql&oq=powershell+connect+to+mssql&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60.5984j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: Thank you Jeff for your reply. I came across a script to install the sql module into powershell. Install-Module -Name SqlServer -Scope CurrentUser. Once the module was installed, I was able to goto ssms, right-click on the database and i was able to get the database prompt in powershell but getting some errors like:
WARNING: Could not obtain SQL Server Service information. An attempt to connect to WMI on 'DISPRODSQL01' failed with the following error: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)) So, i dont know if i have connected and why i am getting that error. Ty

Comment: I also checked out that link you gave me but, I am not using a username and pw, I am using windows authentication.

Answer (score 0):

This is old, and there may be more modern SQL Powershell cmdLets that would also work. On the other hand, this will work anywhere(?) without the need to install extra SQL components.

The following will connect with the credentials of the currently logged on user:

```
$sqlSelect = "SELECT * FROM myView"
$sspi = "server=SERVERXYZ123;database=bigData;Integrated Security=sspi"
$sqlAdap = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter ($sqlSelect, $sspi)
$sqlTable = new-object System.Data.DataTable
$sqlAdap.fill($sqlTable) | out-null # number of rows selected
$sqlTable | foreach { $_ #doSomething }
```